# How to compute a certain determinant?

Tags: matrices, determinant

Let $t \in [0,1/6]$, $n$ be a positive integer, then how to compute the determinant of the following matrix:

$$A=\left[
\begin{matrix}
1-6t&t&t&t&t&0&0&0&0&\dots&t&0&t\\
t&1-6t&t&0&t&t&0&0&0&\dots&t&t&0\\
t&t&1-6t&t&0&t&0&0&0&\dots&0&t&t\\
t&0&t&1-6t&t&t&t&t&0&\dots&0&0&0\\
t&t&0&t&1-6t&t&0&t&t&\dots&0&0&0\\
0&t&t&t&t&1-6t&t&0&t&\dots&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&t&0&t&1-6t&t&t&\dots&0&t&t\\
0&0&0&t&t&0&t&1-6t&t&\dots&0&0&0\\
0&0&0&0&t&t&t&t&1-6t&\dots&0&0&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&\vdots \\
t&t&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&\dots&1-6t&t&t\\
0&t&t&0&0&0&0&0&0&\dots&t&1-6t&t\\
t&0&t&0&0&0&0&0&0&\dots&t&t&1-6t
\end{matrix}
\right]_{3n \times 3n}?$$

Comment: The general rule of construction is unclear. Couldn't you express $M_{ij}=...$?

Comment: In your title, I have suppressed "square matrix" because one can only take determinants on square matrices...

Comment: @JeanMarie: I am seeing this as built from $3\times 3$ blocks, $A$ on the diagonal, and then $C$s on the superdiagonal and top right corner, with $C^T$ in corresponding places below the diagonal. But Haipeng Chen needs to tell us.

Comment: @ancient mathematician : you are right, with for example on the first line,  blocks $\begin{pmatrix}1-6t&t&t\\t&1-6t&t\\t&t&1-6t\end{pmatrix}$,  $\begin{pmatrix}t&t&0\\0&t&t\\t&0&t \end{pmatrix}$, .... $\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$...$\begin{pmatrix}t&0&t\\t&t&0\\0&t&t \end{pmatrix}$,

Comment: @JeanMarie, is your third one right? BTW I misread the corner entries where $C$ and $C^T$ are (happily) swapped.

Comment: You mean the null matrix ? Besides, I thought at first that it is a block circulant matrix: this is not the case...

Comment: I have no time to do it, but by diagonalising the usual $n\times n$ circulant matrix, can't one reduce the given matrix to $n$ $3\times 3$ matrices along the diagonal, and then the determinant is the product of the determinants of these--which being $3\times 3$ are easy to calculate. I think that the answer is $$\prod \det (A+\zeta C+\zeta^{-1} C^T)$$ where the product is over the $n$-th roots of unity $\zeta$.

Comment: @ancientmathematician is right; this is kinda routine.